# Scaling an element while keeping its border radius constant

Tags: html, css, transform, scale, border-radius

I am trying to scale an element on the Y-axis. The element has a border-radius of 20px. I am following [this](https://css-tricks.com/various-methods-for-expanding-a-box-while-preserving-the-border-radius/) tutorial on how to scale an element while keeping its border-radius constant. The TLDR is that for the border to remain constant after scaling it, the border-radius has to be scaled as well. This works if you scale it without animating the transition, as shown in the article provided above. However, when animating it, the border-radius looks really bad during the transition.

Below is an example of this. The right side element in the example below is scaled by 2 vertically, and the border-radius is scaled as well to account for this. You can see the border-radius at the top does not remain constant during the animation and it looks quite jarring to my eye. I was wondering if there was a way to make the border-radius remain unchanged throughout the transition.

https://codepen.io/KR1S71AN/pen/qBQbgYR

Here is an example of this live too.

```css
html { 
    height: 1000px;
}

.single-item {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 40vw;
    height: 40vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.single-item::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 8vmin;
    background: linear-gradient(#000, #f90);
    content: '';
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transform-origin: top;
}

.hover:hover::after {
  border-radius: 8vmin/ 4vmin;
    transform: scale(1, 2)
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class='single-item'></div>
    <div class='single-item hover'></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of transform, which actually stretches your element, just change the height.

```css
html {
  height: 1000px;
}

.single-item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.single-item::after {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 8vmin;
  background: linear-gradient(#000, #f90);
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}

.hover:hover::after {
  height: 200%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class='single-item'></div>
  <div class='single-item hover'></div>
</section>
```

#### Edit

If you need to use transforms, the "more performant" (and non-JS) version would be to animate the border-radius as well. It's a bit wonky, but at least it's smooth.

```css
html { 
    height: 1000px;
}

.single-item {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 40vw;
    height: 40vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.single-item::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 8vmin;
    background: linear-gradient(#000, #f90);
    content: '';
    transition: transform 0.3s, border-radius 0.3s;
    transform-origin: top;
}

.hover:hover::after {
  border-radius: 8vmin / 4vmin;
  transform: scale(1, 2)
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class='single-item'></div>
    <div class='single-item hover'></div>
</section>
```

Comment: This works but it's prohibitively expensive to do on a lot of elements. That is the whole reason why I am trying to use transform: scaleY(), as it doesn't trigger either browser layout or paint computations. Changing the height triggers both I believe.